# spring transaction of JdbcTemplate/HibernateTemplate and HibernateDaoSupport/JdbcDaoSupport

Tags: spring

How transaction is controlled while using `JdbcTemplate`/`HibernateTemplate`and `HibernateDaoSupport`/`JdbcDaoSupport`? I used to check source code and didn't find where the transaction is controlled by `JdbcTemplate`/`HibernateTemplate` and `HibernateDaoSupport`/`JdbcDaoSupport`. 
And In source code `HibernateDaoSupport`/`JdbcDaoSupport` is using `JdbcTemplate`/`HibernateTemplate`, what's the role of `HibernateDaoSupport`/`JdbcDaoSupport` and what's the role of `JdbcTemplate`/`HibernateTemplate`?
Why do we use `JdbcTemplate`/`HibernateTemplate` and `HibernateDaoSupport`/`JdbcDaoSupport`? It seems all sample code is using them. What should I use if I don't want to use them, such as only using spring + hibernate?
If I'm using `JdbcTemplate`/`HibernateTemplate` and `HibernateDaoSupport`/`JdbcDaoSupport`, do I still need to config transaction proxy in xml? If I still need to config transaction proxy in xml, it means it's ok for me to put both `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(user)`and  `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(order)` together, and they're invoked in the same transaction, is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all please forget about `HibernateTemplate` and `HibernateDaoSupport` these classes should be considered deprecated since the release of hibernate 3.0.1 (which was somewhere in 2006!). You should be creating daos/repositories based on a plain hibernate API, as explained in the [Spring Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight). (The same goes for `JpaTemplate` and `JpaDaoSupport`).

`JdbcTemplate` (and all other *Template classes) intend is to make it easier to work with the underlying technology. Once upon a time this was also needed for Hibernate (< 3.0.1), now it isn't.

`JdbcTemplate` makes it easier to work with plain JDBC code. You don't have to get a connection, create a `(Prepared)Statement`, add the parameters, execute the query, iterate over the resultset and convert the `ResultSet`. With the `JdbcTemplate` much of this is hidden and most of it can be written in 1 to 3 lines of code, whereas plain JDBC would require a lot more.

The *Support classes make it easier to gain access to a template but aren't a must to use. Creating a `JdbcTemplate` is quite easy and you don't really need to extend `JdbcDaoSupport`. But you can if you want. For more information a lot is explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-introduction).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I won't use these features in new project. But it's good to know the answer, and it busts me when I don't know. So can anybody explain the answer to me in a little more detail?

Comment: I suggest the reference guide everything is quite clearly explained in there... Links are already in the post.